# Android Studio SDK Manager issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I've installed Android Studio along with sdk , but in sdk manager notifies that sdk has been **partially installed** and also some of the options in sdk like **(sdk tools and sdk updates sites tab are disabled)**. Also I'm not able to add previous or other sdk versions. Sdk Manager show the updates , but its disabled and thus not able to download and install them.

Yes I've tried to run as admin, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The standalone SDK Manager can *only* be run via command line. In other words, the listing of contents prints on the command line - *not* in a GUI.

The Graphical User Interface for the standalone SDK Manager has been *deprecated*.

Yet, there is still a version that can be run on the command line. On Windows this can be from a Command (DOS) window.

The recommended way to manage the Android SDK is to use Android Studio Settings, rather than any standalone SDK Manager. This is a relatively new change. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in SDK manager is still not perfect. Use the standalone SDK manager.